# ArrayList is empty

Tags: java, arraylist, isnullorempty

The issue I would like to receive assistance on is 'ans.add(new ArrayList<>(build))'. My question is, why is that if I do not initiate a new ArrayList, my output for ans is a list of empty lists, as is the case in the second block of code.

I initialized an ArrayList outside of the helper function so I presumed that the state of the ArrayList was preserved, but obviously I was wrong... Any help?

```
public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) {
        if(nums == null || nums.length == 0) return new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

        List<Integer> build = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        helper(nums, 0, build);
        return ans;

    }
    public void helper(int[] nums, int pos, List<Integer> build) {
        if(pos == nums.length) {
            ans.add(new ArrayList<>(build));
            return;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if(!build.contains(nums[i])) {
                build.add(nums[i]);   
                helper(nums, pos+1, build);
                build.remove(build.size()-1);
            }
        }

    }
```

```
public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) {
        if(nums == null || nums.length == 0) return new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

        List<Integer> build = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        helper(nums, 0, build);
        return ans;

    }
    public void helper(int[] nums, int pos, List<Integer> build) {
        if(pos == nums.length) {
            ans.add(build);
            return;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if(!build.contains(nums[i])) {
                build.add(nums[i]);   
                helper(nums, pos+1, build);
                build.remove(build.size()-1);
            }
        }

    }
```

Edit: I know that Java passes a copy of a reference for the parameter value, and in this case I thought I would be building on top of that copy reference and populating it correctly since I do not change the copy's reference location.

Comment: Why is this method both recursive _and_ a loop?  I'm suspicious of the calls to `remove` as well.

Comment: @IanMcLaird Hi, I did not include some context regarding that because I didn't feel that it was necessary. However, to let you know, the loop is there because my goal is to create permutations of an array of integers. Therefore, I want to recursively loop through the array to create all possible combinations. For example, with an array of [1,2,3] I would create -> [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3]...]

Comment: On every iteration of your loop, you're adding a new item to (the end of) `build` and then removing the last item from `build`.  The net effect of that will be an empty list.

Comment: @IanMcLaird Yes, but I use recursion and pass the list. The only time it removes, is after the recursion loop has finished. I think now that it may have to do with the fact that while 'build' is instantiated with an ArrayList, actually adding 'build' does not work because it is in essence of the List interface and therefore you have to convert it to an ArrayList.

Comment: Right, but since you're modifying `build` in place, you're removing the items from it after you've added it to `ans`.  That means that the first element of `ans` is being modified in place (because the elements of `ans` are added as references, not copies), and will therefore be empty once you finally look.  It's not about which implementation of `List` you use, either, all mutable lists will behave this way.

Comment: @IanMcLaird I see what you are saying. That is why a new ArrayList should be created so the contents of it is kept somewhere else in a new reference. The list I add to ans is still being referred to at the same location and being modified. I appreciate your help. If you can put that as the answer I will gladly upvote it! Thanks again.